# Toggle only one div element at same position (hide all other div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I’m new to `jQuery` and struggling with the `.toggle()` function.

I want to display several `<div>`-elements in the same position…but only one at the time. If one `<div>` is opened and a different one is “toggled” it should automatically be closed.
HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    $("#box1").toggle(1000);
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button2").click(function() {
    $("#box2").toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 90px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: green;
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class=box1 id=box1>
    This is Box 1
  </div>

  <div class=box2 id=box2>
    This is Box 2
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="button1">Box1</a>
<a href="#" id="button2">Box2</a>
```

Also, I am pretty sure that I only need one `toggle()` function and not 4 for the task I am trying to achieve…but trying to call on the same one does not seem to work with my different `id`/`class`.
What am I doing wrong/missing here?

Comment: Also, why not just two links? "Toggle box 1" and "Toggle box 2".

Comment: True! This is unneccesary for the example. In the original code these are links to open/close buttons. (i have simplified the example by removing the links.)

Comment: Don't give the boxes unique classes.  You are already giving them unique ids.  You can select them all with a common class to perform part of your desired logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you can use a single document ready function.

In this case, you could also use a single `click` function to handle your toggles. Since you're using trigger links, you'll need a way to reference the target box, but something like this would work with an additional attribute to get the box name. (You could do it with indexes as well, but for ease of use, I've added a `target-box` attribute that has the ID of the desired box.)

I've also added the same `box` class to both divs, you could remove the individual `box1/box2` classes since you have IDs that handle differences already.

I've also added a `toggle` class to the links to give them a more semantic selector and removed the unnecessary 'open/close' duplicates (since `toggle` is designed to handle both)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.toggle').on('click', function(){
    var targetBox = $(this).attr('target-box'); // Find the target box
    
    $('.box').not(targetBox).hide(1000); // Hide all other boxes
    
    $(targetBox).toggle(1000); // Toggle the current state of this one
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 90px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: green;
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1" id="box1">
    This is Box 1
  </div>

  <div class="box box2" id="box2">
    This is Box 2
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="toggle" target-box="#box1">Toggle Box1</a>
<a href="#" class="toggle" target-box="#box2">Toggle Box2</a>
```

Comment: This works perfectly and seems to be the cleanest/shortest solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may do the trick for you. You can hide all elements marked in some way, e.g. all elements of a class. In this snippet I added the class "box" to all boxes, and on open, I first hide all boxes in this way, before showing the specified box.

Now clicking open will open the specified box and close any others, and clicking close will close the specified box.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    $(".box").hide(1000);
    $("#box1").show(1000);
  });
  $("#buttonclose").click(function() {
    $("#box1").hide(1000);
  });
  $("#button2").click(function() {
    $(".box").hide(1000);
    $("#box2").show(1000);
  });
  $("#buttonclose2").click(function() {
    $("#box2").hide(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 90px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: green;
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1" id=box1>
    This is Box 1
  </div>

  <div class="box box2" id=box2>
    This is Box 2
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="buttonclose">Close Box1</a>
<a href="#" id="buttonclose2">Close Box2</a>

<a href="#" id="button1">Open Box1</a>
<a href="#" id="button2">Open Box2</a>
```